# Conditional import Deno

Tags: javascript, typescript, deno

I want my config file optional, I thought of this solution, check if the config file exists and conditionally import my config file but I get `An import declaration can only be used in a namespace or module.deno-ts(1232)`.

`app.ts`

```js
import {existsSync} from 'https://deno.land/std/fs/mod.ts'

if (existsSync('./myconfig.ts')) {
  import {config} from './myconfig.ts'
}
```

`myconfig.ts`

```js
export const config: any = {
  config: "value"
}
```